# Why TestController.createRunProfile does not make the command 'Debug Test' in the context menu in Test Explorer in VS Code

Tags: vscode-extensions

I am currently working on a project using the Test Explorer in Visual Studio Code and I am having trouble with the context menu.

By default, the context menu displays
[image]

If I create a Run profile:

```
this._runProfile = this._testController.createRunProfile('Run', vscode.TestRunProfileKind.Run, this.runHandler, true);
```

and click on the command `Run Test`, then `this.runHandler` is executed.

However, when I create a Debug profile:

```
this._debugProfile = this._testController.createRunProfile('Debug', vscode.TestRunProfileKind.Debug, this.debugHandler, true);
```

the command `Debug Test` is not showing up in the context menu.

I was expecting to see `Debug Test` in the context menu and have it execute `this.debugHandler` every time it is clicked.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

I tried to manually add a command to the `package.json` and register it with a different handler, but I am unsure if this is the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

I found that it was an issue was in my development environment.

Everything was building, linking, but it only worked once and after that the command Debug Test didn't show up again. I thought it was a bug in the api, but it is not.

After doing everything again, it worked well.